# Scaling UIwebview swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I am trying to scale the UIWebView content to the screen of the simulator. However, I can not manage to figure out how to scale the content to the respective IOS device. I have tried a variety of things to change the scaling of the content, but can not find anything on other pages. I am also NOT using storyboards for this project. I am using direct code to make constraints for the app. Here is the code for the UIWebView

```
func handleDownload() {
    //print(123)
    let webView = UIWebView (frame: view.frame)
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://storage.com")!))



}
```

I have tried using this code:

```
func zoomToFit() {
if theWebView.respondsToSelector(#selector(self.scrollView)) {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView = theWebView.scrollView()
    var zoom: Float = theWebView.bounds.size.width /   scrollView.contentSize.width
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = zoom
    scrollView.setZoomScale(zoom, animated: true)
   }
}
```

This doesnt seem to work..

Thank You!

Comment: use storyboard with constraint should solve it

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am also trying for zooming webview thru IBAction. please help me out......

Comment: Are you trying to view the document through a downloaded link? (Ex: firebase storage)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this and found you should set it scaleable in HTML. Like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width" />
```

And you should set it scalesPageToFit to false. Like this:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = false
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The file that the code retrieves is a word doc so the HTML did not work. However, when I used the second part, I set the code to true and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my problem with webView scaling:

```
func yhandleDownload() {

    let webView = UIWebView (frame: view.frame)
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "database.url")!))

    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

All that is needed is the last line of code to have everything scale. (at least for anyone wanting to use this method)